# When forecasting using Prophet (in R), how do I account for pre- and post- holiday effects, in irregular public holidays, such as Easter?

Tags: python, r, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I'm building a model in Prophet (R) to forecast daily sales over a period of time.

I'm currently using Prophet's in-built holiday database to build my model, see below:

```
df <- read.csv(subs_filepath,header=TRUE)

df <- rename(df, ds = dte)
df <- rename(df, y = trans)
df$ds <- as.Date(df$ds)

df$floor <- 0


lockdown <- data.frame(
  holiday=c('lockdown'),
  ds=c('2020-03-21'),
  lower_window=c(0),
  ds_upper=c('2022-02-26'),
  upper_window=c(708),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
lockdown$ds <- as.Date(lockdown$ds)
lockdown$ds_upper <- as.Date(lockdown$ds_upper)


m <- prophet(seasonality_mode = 'multiplicative',holidays = lockdown)
m <- add_regressor(m,'sales',mode = 'multiplicative')
m <- add_country_holidays(m, country_name = 'UK')
m <- fit.prophet(m, df)
```

Our business is highly impacted by public holidays, but most importantly, much of the impact is in the run-up to (and after) the holidays, e.g. people purchasing gifts in the run-up to Christmas, rather than Christmas day itself.

This is fine for Christmas, which occurs on the same date each year, and so is automatically recognised using Prophet's seasonality model. The issue is for holidays like Easter, which are on different days every year.

My question is, will Prophet automatically notice and account for the trend before and after each holiday? If not, then how can I account for this?

In the [Prophet guide](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#prior-scale-for-holidays-and-seasonality), it refers to using `prior.scale`, though I'm not entirely clear what it does. It seems like it simply increases or decreases the coefficient of the holiday regressor, but I'm not sure if it will change how the model responds to the pre and post periods.

Alternatively, I could add the pre- and post- periods in as holidays or extra regressors. The issue with this (other than it being fiddly and time-consuming), is that any sales increase driven by the holiday will build up over time (e.g. smaller impact in early December than late December, when considering Christmas), which a single multiplicative or additive regressor with a constant coefficient won't account for.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue with this (other than it being fiddly and time-consuming), is that any sales increase driven by the holiday will build up over time (e.g. smaller impact in early December than late December, when considering Christmas), which a single multiplicative or additive regressor with a constant coefficient won't account for.

Couple of ideas here.

1. If you use weekly seasonality that should do a pretty decent job for the holidays that don't move. That would mean less fiddly and time-consuming things to do with regressors.
2. Use regressors with values that you model separately that seek to mimic that build up and decay pre and post holiday. So the values from Dec 20 - 27 might be (0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 0.25, 0.1). Getting those values is a separate issue.

In a previous job/company I dealt with this, but only worried about 2 days pre/post each holidays. I modeled each one as a separate regressor. If this is a high-value process, the time is well worth it. Just do things in a way so that your regressor values get re-modeled dynamically. That will make this something that doesn't have to be constantly adjusted, even as you potentially use it for years.